# Duplicate row for the current table

Tags: jquery

I have some code that allows for a specific table to have the last row duplicated:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".addbutton").click(function() {
            $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

So that works for my table with ID of `mytable`. [See working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g9aoe6bj/)

What I want to do is make the code work for any table on the same page. So I would have multiple `add` buttons - and when you press `add` it will make the closet table row duplicate.

This is what I tried to guess - but it doesnt work

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".addbutton").click(function() {
            $(this).closest('table tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter($(this).closest('table tbody>tr:last'));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I make the code work for multiple tables on the same page? [JSFiddle of what I currently have that does not work...](http://jsfiddle.net/46dtecmj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your HTML structure, you cannot use `closest()`, but you need to use the `prev()` method, using a delegated `click` event on each `.addbutton` button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addbutton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not really needed..depends on situation 
    var $tr = $(this).prev('table').find('tbody > tr:last');
    $tr.clone(true).insertAfter($tr);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mdjrnskp/2/)

`closest()` goes upwards in the DOM hierarchy, and the table element you are seeking isn't there, but it is actually a sibling of the "add" button.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).prev('table').find('tr:last');
    tr.clone(true).insertAfter(tr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Ipsum</td>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Consequetor</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cloning</td>
            <td>....</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn">Add</button>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Ipsum</td>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Consequetor</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cloning</td>
            <td>....</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn">Add</button>
```